# Stop non-VPN traffic from going through VPN

Tags: vpn

I have set up a L2TP/IPSec VPN set up on my phone. Now all my network traffic goes through the VPN. However I am not a fan of that. Not only does it add unnecessary overhead, it also makes me unable to access any host in my current LAN. I only want traffic to and from VPN hosts to go through the actual VPN. (or even better, a setting to toggle that). (How) can I do that without rooting my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with the help of a friend i figured it out myself. Basicly you have to go to advanced settings of the VPN profile and put the subnet of the VPN as forwarding route.

If you want to have an easy time to change inbetween tunneling everything and not, i'd say the best approach is to create two profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I have an openvpn setup. I'm in Mexico, and using some services that can only be reached from a US ISP. In my setup, I have two routers. The one from the Mexican telephone company, and another as a wireless hot spot, plugged into the first.

Everything that goes through the second router is on the VPN. Everything that by-passes the second router, and uses only first goes through the Mexican ISP.

I have turned off the radio in the first router, and can only use it 'wired', But there is no need to do that if the two routers are set to channels that are far enough apart.